# Background image does not extends completely in vuejs

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vue-router

There are questions like this one but none has satisfactory solutions.

I am trying to insert a background image to a vuejs component but the image does not extend to the full page rather it extends only to the component. Even though I have `background-size: cover`. What am I missing?

Please Look at the white patch above "PI"

[image: look at the white patch above "PI"]

I am designing a login page so the logincard.vue code is

```
<template>
    <div class="body-of-login">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="card card-container">
            /* Some more code here */
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<style >
.body-of-login {
    /* height: 100%; */
    min-height: 100vh;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-image: url("../../assets/ocean.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Also this is the code for my App.vue

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <Navbar title="Post-IT" />
        <router-view />
        <Footer />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
export default {
    name: "app",
    components: {
        Footer,
        Navbar,
    },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
#app {
    font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    text-align: center;
    color: #2c3e50;
}

#nav {
    padding: 30px;

    a {
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #2c3e50;

        &.router-link-exact-active {
            color: #42b983;
        }
    }
}
</style>
```

Comment: `background-position: top center;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to set the position of the container to fixed:

```
.body-of-login {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

or maybe you have a margin from a headline h1 on top?

Comment: removed margin-top from this component and the background extends full :) Thanks
also, along with the background the login box also  gets attached to the Navbar. What change needs to be done in CSS to shift it down? just the login box.